# ajax data echo is showing html code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery AJAX to call a parameterised function on dynamic button click. 
Script and function is working fine. only problem is, it is showing all the HTML code into alert box. right from  to all my dynamic HTML table. I don't need to show HTML code, only need to show successfull messages. Please someone help me.
Thanks

PHP Code

```
echo "<td><input type='button' name='disable' value='Disable' onClick='disable($id);'/></td>";
```

AJAX Code:

```
function disable(id) { 
    jQuery.ajax({   type: 'Post', 
                    url: '', 
                    data: {action: 'delete', ID: id} 
    })
    .done(function(data) { 
        alert("Data Saved: " + data); 
        location.reload();
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Show us the PHP code

Comment: Show us the jQuery code too

Comment: It's sometimes happens, when we forget to use exit(); in php code

Comment: PHP code: echo "<td><input type='button' name='disable' value='Disable' onClick='disable($id);'/></td>";  AJAX Code: function disable(id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'Post', url: '',
        data: {action: 'delete', ID: id}
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + data); 
  location.reload();
    });
}

Comment: edit your post with the code Pooja - not as a comment :)

Comment: The alert box shows the successful messages  but shows HTML code as well. I want to omit HTML code..

Comment: where is success message all I can see is button :P

Comment: if you are echoing HTML code in your php page this is the data that is returned from the AJAX call so it makes sense that alerting(data) alerts the html code. If you return JSON or just the data from the php page - you can then use  your success frunction to build the html to insert into the HTML page

Comment: PHP code: <code> echo "<td><input type='button' name='disable' value='Disable' onClick='disable($id);'/></td>";  AJAX Code: function disable(id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'Post', url: '',
        data: {action: 'delete', ID: id}
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + data); 
  location.reload();
    });
} </code>

Comment: Show ALL the PHP Code, not just one line of it

Comment: just show your whole php file

Comment: just to re-iterate "alert("Data Saved: " + data)" will alert whatever you are returning from your php page - ie: data - is not what you sent to the php page - but what is returned from it. you need to consider what is the returned data from the php page.

Comment: you have no url set so ajax is going to make request to current page url  which is obviously html and what will be returned

Comment: Why have to sent the Html structure from php, why not just the message and let query do the rest?

Comment: I am echoing HTML table may be thats why showing in alert box

Comment: @PoojaKshatriya Wow, you are genius :) :P

Comment: @charlietfl comment is the answer! I'm just questioning your decision.

Comment: Can't set url.. All the code is in the same php file